Why am I getting \u0010 returned from Encoding.ASCII.GetString() when source byte array has simple bytes in it
I am trying to use C# to read/write some old datafiles which were written using Delphi and which only contain ASCII based data, some of the data represents Pascal strings which, you might know, have the length stored in the first byte.
I have opened the files using a FileStream then used the Read() method to read the data into a buffer (byte array).  I can see the byte array has the value 16 (decimal) at the first byte I intend to read from this buffer.
However, when I use the Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 18, 127) to read the buffer into a string, the resulting string gets the '\u0010' string as the first character, which screws everything up.
Any thoughts on how I can avoid this.  I would prefer not to have to recode using a StreamReader in order to add the ANSII encoding... it is all char[] based and still might not work.

Are you sure that you get the string \u0010 and not just the debugger displaying that instead of the unprintable character? Check the length of the returned string and see if it is 127 chars or 132 chars.

"you might know, have the length stored in the first byte." Short Strings but there are others. You can garantuee that you only have Short Strings here? If then just call  Encoding.ASCII.GetString without the byte that contains the length. You decided on the 18 and 127 here. Just take the correct position and length. When you know its 16 bytes why reading 127?

@Heartware Unfortunately yes. This is reinforced by the fact that the GetBytes() returns two bytes for the first character

@Ralf The Delphi code only used short strings, all use the length byte.  The data is essentially in fixed length fields so, by reading the fixed length, I get nulls for the remainder of the field but the read pointer moves to the correct next position of the next data field

@Mike correct positioning might be relevant for reading from the FileStream. But there is no stream positioning involved when calling Encoding.ASCII.GetString. Just read as much as you need there and not more.


I can see the byte array has the value 16 (decimal) at the first byte
...
the resulting string gets the '\u0010' string as the first character

Decimal 16 is hex 10, i.e. 0x10 or expressed as unicode: \u0010. The values are the same - the IDE/debugger is simply displaying the DLE character as the unicode string \u0010 because non-printable characters are easily misunderstood otherwise; hence this is the correct interpretation of this data via ASCII (or ANSI, or UTF8). There is no problem here (perhaps other than that DLE is very unusual in most text formats).
If the point here is that the 16 is the length prefix, then you are going to need to read that yourself before handing the data to an Encoding (such as ASCII). It isn't the Encoding's job to know about the framing rules of Delphi. You may also need to discover what Delphi does for longer strings - i.e. how does it encode a string of length 150? or 250? or 1080? It presumably can't just use a single byte, so: what are the rules for that? These are questions for you to figure out, and then write a parser that reads the first (byte or bytes) to calculate the length, then read that much data. You might also want to check whether the rules are "bytes" vs "characters", (which can be very different if Delphi supports characters outside ASCII), and whether it uses ASCII, UTF8, or some (hopefully defined) ANSI code-page.

All strings are <=255 length (Delphi short strings). The issue I have is that the GetString() reads the bytes but when I try to re-encode the resulting string, the first character is being interpreted as a two-byte character and I get an extra character at the start.  So 17 bytes (length + string) eventually becomes 18 bytes.

@Mike you sked about GetString, but any re-encode step is GetBytes, presumably? Either way: you should not use Encoding for this first byte - instead, read/write that manually separately. Do you perhaps have code we can play with here?

there is no encoding explicitly possible using the file reader/writer methods. It's the combination of a getstring from the file then getbytes to them write back to the file that stuffs up. I read 17 bytes into the string but the same string going back to the file via the getbytes ends up generating 18.  I'll try to knock up an example which doesn't use a file.

@Mike please do; this could be as simple as a BOM, but without code: we can only guess. Code is king, for details.

@Mike also note: what exactly you mean by "the file reader/writer methods" is important, but: most of those APIs are intended for things that are raw text, and a Delphi string: is not raw text. So: it is entirely likely that you'll need some extra code here. It might just be a few extra lines, but: the details matter. If you want to represent bytes in a simple app: base-64 is easy, Convert.FromBase64String, etc
